# Conduit fill for (slotted) wire ducts?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

Table 1 of chapter 9 of the National Electrical Code (of the US) allows us to use up to 53%, 31% or 40% (and 60% in some cases) of the cross-sectional area of a *conduit* or *tubing* (EMT, PVC, etc.), when 1, 2 or more than 2 wires pass through such conduit/tubing, respectively. On the other hand, article 378.22 allows us to use up to 20% of the cross-sectional area of a *wireway*.

Is there an article or table that tells us the maximum cross-sectional area we can fill in a *slotted wire duct*? I'm not sure if a (slotted) wire duct is a type of a wireway.

Just to clarify, by "slotted wire duct" I mean these:

[image: Slotted wire duct]

*Figure 1. [Image source](https://www.hellermanntyton.com/competences/wiring-ducts-heladuct).*

Comment: Wire management devices like this are not used in premises power wiring but if they were you would start the derate at 30 current carrying  conductors, signal conductors are not counted. But you are correct not used in premises wiring.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @EdBeal. Where I work, I've seen wire ducts being used to house electricity current-carrying conductors (#12, 10 and 8 AWG). I'm not sure if that's common in other places or if its even allowed by the Code. Is it a violation?

Comment: Regardless, you're going to have 4-circuit maximum for thermal reasons, unless the wireway is <4'.  Also the pictured item is not a legal wireway for AC power, though you can run Ethernet and fiber in there to your heart's content, in which case the thermal rule does not apply.

Comment: If your jurisdiction calls that an aux gutter type of wireway then 20% and 30 current carrying conductors are the limit. That type of wire management device is required to be inside a cabinet or listed enclosure for power wiring. I have used them extensively but never for power in premises wiring only for power limited and signal wiring. I believe it would be a code violation outside a listed box or panel. Inside a enclosure the rules change also.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine “Also the pictured item is not a legal wireway for AC power” // Which article says it’s not allowed? Just to check.

Comment: @alejnavab 110.2, 110.3(B), and Chapter 3's list of allowed wiring methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panduit classifies this as raceways according to the image, taken from the catalog. Covered in NFPA 79 (13.5). Raceways are defined earlier in the document to include wireways.[image: Wire Fill Formula]

ETA: As @ThreePhaseEel mentioned below, NFPA 79 is a document intended for industrial control panels.

Comment: Note that you should explain that NFPA 79 is only applicable *inside* an industrial control plane enclosure

Comment: That is correct. NFPA 79 is for Industrial control panels; however, from the image we can conclude that the manufacturer's terminology for the image OP posted is "Raceway".

Comment: Side note: it seems the above image was taken from **[this document](https://www.panduit.com/content/dam/panduit/en/products/media/0/70/570/8570/101478570.pdf)**.